# Sorted Matrix Search

Tags: java, arrays, search, matrix, netbeans

I keep receiving an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds on the line directly after the for loop.  I would also wondering how I could continue to loop the matrix to iterate the row or column until the target is reached.

In the given matrix, I want to start in the bottom left hand corner. If the target value is less than the selected number then the row moves up.  If the target value is greater than the selected number then column moves one to the right.

```
 public static void optimizedSearch(int matrix[][], int array_size, int target) {
    int row = 0;
    int col = array_size-1;
    boolean found = false;
    int comparison_counter = 0;
    int end = array_size * 2;

    //while (!found) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100 && !found; i++) {
        if (matrix[row][col] < target ) {
            row++;
            comparison_counter++;
        } else if (matrix[row][col] > target) {
            col--;
            comparison_counter++;
        } else if (matrix[row][col] == target) {
            found = true;
        } else if ((i == end) && (found == false)) {
            found=false;
        }
    }// end for loop

    if (found == true) {
        System.out.println(target + " found in " + comparison_counter + " number of comparisons using optimized search");

    } else 
        System.out.println(target + " not found in " + comparison_counter + " number of comparisons using optimized search");

} //end optimizedSearch
```

Comment: You are not using `i` in the loop.

Comment: The error is there b'cos lets say when i=0, which means your code only has the handle to the 1st row in the array, but the row value (array_size) that has been passed is lets say 3, so your logic is trying to get a handle to the 4th row, something like: if (matrix[4][0] < target) {, which is out of bounds at the moment